# Update the flag column based on other 4 flags columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Table Example]

I have to write a update query to update the column "IS_DUPLICATE_MATCH"=1 when any 3 (or all 4) columns out of the rest 4 columns are 1.

If less than 3 columns are 1, then "IS_DUPLICATE_MATCH"=0.

Consider the above example.

Comment: Calculate a sum of your flags for the current row and compare it to `3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
update t
    set is_duplicate_match = (case when is_phone_match + is_address_match + is_name_match + is_email_match >= 3
                                   then 1 else 0
                               end);
```

Or, you could use arithmetic and make the `update` less understandable:

```
update t
    set is_duplicate_match = (is_phone_match + is_address_match + is_name_match + is_email_match) / 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE and calculate the sum and apply update as given below:

```sql
;WITH CTE_UpdateTable AS
(
SELECT Is_Duplicate_Match, Is_Phone_Match + Is_Address_match + Is_Name_Match + Is_Email_Match as total_Match
FROM Table
)
UPDATE CTE_UpdateTabl
SET Is_Duplicate_Match = CASE WHEN total_Match >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I will surely try above approaches .I'm sure every answer will work.